# parsing out data segment from a TCP stream

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ipad

Im having some trouble with receiving packet data from a TCP stream.  I think this is due in part to not understanding the servers responses.

my code (objective c):

```
unsigned type=0; 
unsigned bufferFirstByte=0;
unsigned bufferSecondByte=0;
unsigned bufferThirdByte=0;

NSScanner *hexToInt = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[mutableBuffer objectAtIndex:0]];
[hexToInt scanHexInt:&bufferFirstByte];

hexToInt = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[mutableBuffer objectAtIndex:1]];
[hexToInt scanHexInt:&bufferSecondByte];

hexToInt = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[mutableBuffer objectAtIndex:2]];
[hexToInt scanHexInt:&bufferThirdByte];

hexToInt = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[mutableBuffer objectAtIndex:0]];
[hexToInt scanHexInt:&type];

int len = (bufferSecondByte<<8)+bufferSecondByte;

if (![mutableBuffer count]<(3+len)) {
    
    NSArray *payload  = [mutableBuffer subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,([mutableBuffer count] - 2))];
    NSLog(@"length %d",len);
    [self processReceive:type length:len payload:payload];

}
```

is some what modelled from [this](https://github.com/CommandFusion/CIP) javascript code:

```
self.receive = function (itemName, data) {
        self.log("Receiving: " + self.toHex(data));
        self.ourData += data;
        while (self.ourData.length >= 3) {
            var type = self.ourData.charCodeAt(0);
            var len = (self.ourData.charCodeAt(1) << 8) + self.ourData.charCodeAt(2);
            if (self.ourData.length < (3 + len)) {      // sanity check: buffer doesn't contain all the data advertised in the packet
                break;  
            }
            var payload = self.ourData.substr(3,len);
            self.ourData = self.ourData.substr(3 + len);
            self.processMessage(type, len, payload);    // process payload
        }
    };
```

The reason for the modeling is that the command fusion javascript project is talking to the same server I am (a crestron controller).

However I could never get the len thing to work and I think thats whats causing my problem.  When looking at a sample packet (05:00:06:00:00:03:00:52:00) the len would equal 1280 (see math above) even though the data portion is only 9bytes.

Currently my code will work but it misses certain data.  This happens because of the streaming that TCP does (some packets are conjoined while others are fragmented).  But without knowing the data segment size I cannot fix the issue and I believe the answer to that is the `len` variable.  But I dont see how to properly implement it.

**My question comes down to this.  How can I determine the size of the data segment from this `len` variable or control my receive method to only except one data segment at a time (which from my research is not possible since TCP is made as a stream)?**

I have a feeling there will be questions so Im going to attempt to answer a few of them  here.

A. How do you come up with 1280:  look at the math in the method `((self.ourData.charCodeAt(1) << 8) + self.ourData.charCodeAt(2);)`  (5<<8)+0=1280d

B. Why are you using different indexes:
You will notice that the index for what data goes where (`payload, len, type`).  This is merely because they have their payload/data bytes as a string and myn is an array.  in the end it is the same data being referenced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i got some help from ([this group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Crestron/message/150171)) which you might not be able to see without a login for the group.  in any case there is a 3 byte header.  so my len which is 6 and not 1280 like i thought is actually 9 once the 3 is added for the header.  and this gets me the value i was loooking for (9) since the data segment is 9bytes.

Thanks for the suggestions david, one up for some good basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following logic:

1) Do you have enough bytes to determine the length? If not, receive some more bytes and try again.

2) Do you have enough bytes to have one complete unit? If not, receive some more bytes and try again.

3) Extract one complete unit using the decoded length from step 1 and process it.

4) If we have no leftover bytes, we are done.

5) Return to step 1 to process the leftover bytes.

Comment: but what i dont get is how to know how big "one complete unit" is.  sometimes packet length is 9bytes other times 4bytes even up to 25bytes and beyond.

Comment: You explained how to determine the length in the question. It's computed from the second and third bytes. In your example, the length was 1,280.

Comment: but what does that 1280 computer to?  like i said the example i gave was 9bytes.  even if 1280 is bits thats still 160bytes

Comment: i think my math was wrong, the length im getting now for a packet like that is 6 but still not 9 like i would suspect

Comment: In the example, you had read enough bytes to determine the length but not enough bytes to process one complete unit. Per step 2, you receive some more bytes and try again. (It also seems you may have a separate issue of not understanding the protocol. Is it documented anywhere?)

Comment: @David - we're so close on this, I don't want to ask a whole new question. You seem pretty knowledgeable, perhaps you know the right search phrase. What if there is no end-of-unit marker between messages that need processing? How can we combine the use of asynchronous (non-blocking) sockets style and a recursive decent parsers to efficiently converse over a channel. Each completed root-child is a message available for processing. Lookahead parsing would be a complication, but I'm not sure how much of one. I just can't seem to find any discussion/guidance on that combo. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to that question is my answer. Extract a complete unit based on the length information, then process what is left.